# Plumbing: Reuse black pipes and supply lines after a month

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water

I just installed a Vanity Base and Countertop last month. Its too small, lower quality, so we are going to install a new one. Should we repurchase the silver supply lines and black pipes below? or is it okay to reuse ones that are only a month old. We have to disassemble and reassemble them, in same configuration,  when removing then installing new cabinet.

I heard sometimes pipes deteriorate, less their fitting when they are taken apart and reinstalled.

[image]

Comment: I replaced our bath vanity 2 years ago. I reused all the PVC drain plumbing that was there when we moved into the house 30 years ago. Who knows how long it had been there prior to that. I _did_ replace the washers inside the screw fittings because the fit was a little loose & sloppy, so for a few bucks I figured I'd save myself some worry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If not leaking or too short, reuse.

They are made to last many, many years.

The black drain pipes have some adjustment made in, they can be turned some if new sink not exact position as old.

Comment: ok , thanks, 
I heard sometimes pipes deteriorate, less their fitting when they are taken apart and reinstalled.

Comment: Pipes do deteriorate, but we are talking 40 to 100 years.  Just be careful undoing them and putting them back together.